Merging Different Groups for Cox Regression
I have time to event data for subjects from different groups, and I use group features as covariates for cox regression. For example, I have 100 subjects from group A, and 200 subjects from group B, and I am using the features that each group can possibly have as covariates, as the specific feature of the group is more important than the group itself for my study. In this case, do I need to sample an equal number of subjects from each group, or is it okay to use all the data, including varying numbers of subjects from each group, for Cox regression?

No need to artificially balance groups, you can use all the data.
